# Mex - Executing command 'which gcc' hangs

Tags: matlab, gcc, compilation, mex

I am having trouble compiling my .c mex file.  In particular, I cannot tell if it's taking a long time to compile (it is a VERY large program, ~60MB of code), or if it's misconfigured or having some other problem.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit, MATLAB 2015a, with gcc configured.  My c file is called test4.c.

So, I run:

```
mex -v test4.c

Verbose mode is on.
Neither -compatibleArrayDims nor -largeArrayDims is selected.
     Using -compatibleArrayDims. In the future, MATLAB will require the use of
     -largeArrayDims and remove the -compatibleArrayDims option.
     For more information:
     http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/upgrading-mex-files-to-use-64-bit-api.html.
... Looking for compiler 'gcc' ...
... Executing command 'which gcc' ...
```

And that's all I get.  If it's doing more stuff, I would have expected verbose mode would print it.

Is it compiling?  How do I know?  Why would it get stuck here (and what is "which gcc" doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command `which gcc` would normally just tell you where `gcc` is installed on your system, something that should be fairly quick. You can try it from a shell yourself to confirm:

```
pax> which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

So I'd be very surprised if that's what it's actually taking a long time to do.

The best way to find out is to probably open up a terminal and enter the command, putting your user name in where it has `<user>`:

```
ps -fu<user> >/tmp/pslist.txt
```

In my case, that would be `ps -fupax`.

This will give you a list of all your processes, which you can then use to track down what process in the tree is currently running, such as:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
pax       3103  3099  0 11:42 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
pax       3137  3103  0 11:48 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f
```

Start by finding the `mex -v test4.c` process (under `CMD`) and getting it's process ID (PID). From there, you look for all processes that have that same number in the parent process ID (PPID) field. In my case above, the `bash` process is the parent of the `ps` one.

If you follow the tree down far enough, you'll find your errant process. Assuming it's relatively long-lived, it will be the one that's still there when checking the `ps` output twenty seconds apart (for example) - it's also more likely to have consumed more CPU time so you can look in the `TIME` column for non-zero entries.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm a little confused.  How will I know if a process is errant?  I should also note that I just ran this, and weirdly enough, MATLAB isn't listed.  This is supposed to list all processes, right?  I only get:  ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
1000      6369  3261  0 16:50 pts/4    00:00:00 bash
1000      7942  6369  0 20:56 pts/4    00:00:00 ps -f

Comment: @user650261, the errant process will most likely be the one at the bottom of the tree (not the parent of any other), assuming it's there for a decent amount of CPU time (you can use the `TIME` field to determine that). As to the other matter, I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  Based on that, I get that an output that looks like: "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/cc1 -quiet -I /usr/local/MATLAB/R2015a/extern/include... (lots more args)"  From this, I assume it means it's in the middle of the compilation process (and thus must be past the "which").  Is that suspicion correct?

Comment: @user650261, I would think so. Ideally, do the same `ps` command 30 seconds later and see if that PID still exists. If it does, it's a long compilation. As stated, you can also check the `TIME` column to see if it's using a lot of CPU time.

Comment: Thanks.  I've narrowed this down to gcc, so I'm going to start a new questions specifically about gcc.  I'll return here if/when I make progress.